# Using html to canvas but also has SVG

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas

I am using html2canvas but I can't tell if SVG is supported.  I tried the following and have a SVG tag in my html document but that data is not converted to canvas.  The images and CSS are converted.

```
<head>
  <title>jsPDF</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>   

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.PLUGINTEMPLATE.js"></script>    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/rgbcolor.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/StackBlur.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/rgbcolor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/canvg.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/html2canvas.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/PDF.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {          
            $("#runpdf").click(function(event) {                                    
                html2canvas(document.body, {
                    onrendered: function(canvas) {
                        var doc = new jsPDF();
                        doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), 'jpeg', 15, 40, 180, 160);                        
                        doc.save('test2.pdf');                      
                    }
                });
            });             
        }); 
    </script>   
    <style type="text/css">    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  ... with SVG tag here
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

SVG is not supported in html2canvas. http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

The [latest alpha version](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases) (0.5.0+) supports svg elements.

However, style definitions for svg elements defined in stylesheets are not applied to the generated canvas. This can be patched by adding style definitions to the svg elements before calling html2canvas.

Inspired on [this article](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/01/21/convert-svg-to-png/), I've created this:

```
function generateStyleDefs(svgDomElement) {
  var styleDefs = "";
  var sheets = document.styleSheets;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var rules = sheets[i].cssRules;
    for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
      var rule = rules[j];
      if (rule.style) {
        var selectorText = rule.selectorText;
        var elems = svgDomElement.querySelectorAll(selectorText);

        if (elems.length) {
          styleDefs += selectorText + " { " + rule.style.cssText + " }\n";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  var s = document.createElement('style');
  s.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
  s.innerHTML = "<![CDATA[\n" + styleDefs + "\n]]>";
  //somehow cdata section doesn't always work; you could use this instead:
  //s.innerHTML = styleDefs;

  var defs = document.createElement('defs');
  defs.appendChild(s);
  svgDomElement.insertBefore(defs, svgDomElement.firstChild);
}

// generate style definitions on the svg element(s)
generateStyleDefs(document.getElementById('svgElementId'));
```